# Importing a js library with no export in Angular 2.0.0 with Ancular CLI and Webpack

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

My project is based on Angular 2.0.0 and is built using Angular CLI and Webpack.

I need to import a js library (namely xmltojson.js from `https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmltojson`) which defines a variable (`xmlToJSON`) which itself references a function. There is no export in the js library, just the definition of the variable and the function.

Which is the recommended way to import such a library in my app?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A quick'n'dirty but functional way is this one:

1. Add your 3rd party dependency defined in `package.json` to the `angular-cli.json` `apps[0].scripts` array. In this particular case it would be: `"../node_modules/xmltojson/lib/xmltojson.js"`.
2. Declare a variable `declare var xmlToJSON: any;` in your class. Since the original file `xmltojson.js` declares a variable with the same name it will work.
3. Happily call the functions of the library! Eg.: `xmlToJSON.parseString(testXMLtext);`

The other way is to use [Typings](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typings). It might be cleaner.